How to refresh cached files for a PWA added to home screen?
On Android Chrome, I created a home screen shortcut to my PWA by tapping the "Add to Home screen" menu option in Chrome.
When I launch the app via this shortcut, the Chrome address bar is not visible, so I can't tap the "Refresh" button to reload the app after I make changes to its code.  So the app loads with cached files (i.e. old JS files, etc) and doesn't work properly.  I can delete the shortcut and recreate it from a refreshed copy of the app in Chrome, but that seems like overkill.
How can I force a refresh of the app and all associated files (same as tapping "refresh" in Chrome) when accessing the app via home screen shortcut?  Should I just add a button to my app that says "refresh"?  This seems a bit crude and possibly unnecessary.
